# How does radixsort work on strings in R?

Tags: r, sorting, radix-sort

I tried to generate some ASCII-string vectors and sorted them using `sort` and `sort(..., method="radix")`; however the sorted vectors are DIFFERENT! I tried to read through the radixsort help and these were nothing to suggest that radixsort should sort the string vector in any other fashion. Is this a bug or a "feature" of radix sort?

Please see the MWE below

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
bs = replicate(10, rawToChar(sample(as.raw(32:126), 2, replace=T)))

bs_sorted = sort(bs)
bs_radixsorted = sort(bs, method="radix")

bs_sorted
# "[%" "30" "3u" "9C" "aD" "d~" "Di" "iO" "Vv" "y^"
bs_radixsorted
# "30" "3u" "9C" "Di" "Vv" "[%" "aD" "d~" "iO" "y^"
```

I am running R 3.4.3 on Windows 10 64 bit.

**More info**
MS Excel sorts it the way `sort` sorts the string, perhaps `sort` is the more canonical way to sort?

Comment: See the "Details" section of `?sort` -- "radix" does not depend on current locale. As a simple example, `lcl = Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE"); Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C"); identical(sort(bs), sort(bs, method="radix")); Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", lcl); identical(sort(bs), sort(bs, method="radix"))`

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but the problem seems to be limited to how the sorting algorithm treats symbols and uppercase letters.  The two algorithms agree if you use just numbers:

```
 bs = sample(1:100, 10)
```

or just lower case letters:

```
bs = replicate(10, paste(sample(letters, 2, replace = T), collapse = ""))
```

but not if you add in some symbols:

```
bs = replicate(10, paste(sample(c(letters[1:2], "*", "%"), 1, replace = T), collapse = ""))
```

or if you mix upper and lower case letters:

```
bs = replicate(10, paste(sample(c(letters[1:2], toupper(letters[1:2])), 1, replace = T), collapse = ""))
```

So, it looks like radixsort puts all upper case letters ahead of any lower case letter (eg `B` before `a`), while the default method sorts `A` and `a` before `B` or `b`.  Additionally, the two methods put symbols before letters, but seem to use the inverse ordering of symbols.

I can't say *why* this is, however, or how to turn it off.